# How can I throttle the rate of messages with a transparent proxy server?

Tags: proxy, transparent-proxy

I am trying to run a client software that connects to a socket server and downloads data.

My problem is that the socket server has a max rate of messages per second, and it disconnects a client if the rate is exceeded.

But the client doesn't have the throttling logic coded correctly and the server disconnects the client every time the client tries to connect. This is happening because the server is telling the client that there are more than 50 data points to be updated, and the client is trying to update everything at once.

I cannot change the client, since I don't have the source code. I can't fix the server either.

What is the easiest way to have a transparent proxy that will throttle the number of messages per second from the client to the server? I can select the socket ports easily, so all I need is software that can queue the queries if they get up to the 50 messages per second limit.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for the help!